# Weird Debugger Behavior

Tags: visual-c++, winapi

The following code snippet behaves in Debug mode (VC++ 2005) differently than in Release:

```
HANDLE hFileRead;
hFileRead = CreateFile(pszListFile,           //    lpFileName,
                       GENERIC_READ,          //    dwDesiredAccess,
                       FILE_SHARE_READ,       //    dwShareMode,
                       NULL,                  //    lpSecurityAttributes,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,         //    dwCreationDisposition,
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, //    dwFlagsAndAttributes,
                       0);                    //    hTemplateFile
```

In Release mode it works perfectly.
In Debug mode, it it returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE in hFileRead.
Further retrieving GetLastError() reveals system error 3:

> ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND ("The system
>   cannot find the path specified.")

This is weird. In Release mode it can find it but in Debug mode it cannot find it? How is this possible?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running on a 64-bit operating system?  Don't put stuff in c:\program files, it is virtualized.

Comment: +1 for the creative attempt. No, I am not running a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did not occur again. Abandoned until further notice.

Answer (score 0):

The difference can in in the current directory, if pszListFile contains relative path.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. pszListFile is a 100% absolute path, verified in the debugger as well. So this isn't it.

Comment: I remember that "File doesn't exist" is 2, and not 3, maybe I am wrong... What is exact pszListFile value, try to print it using OutputDebugString.

Comment: The exact pszListFile value is "C:\Program Files\TestCo\TestApp\list.txt". Note the difference between ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2) and ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND (3).